# Issue with antivirus software warning during execution of MASM (Machine Specific Assembly Language) code

Tags: assembly, masm, antivirus

First of all, my English is not very good, and if there are any parts of my description that are unclear.

I have a question regarding Assembly Language (MASM). I have recently started learning MASM using Irvine's textbook. I have been following the exercises in the textbook and writing programs accordingly. I am using Visual Studio 2022 and have downloaded the library from the author's website.

However, when I finished writing the code and tried to execute it, my antivirus software raised an alert stating that my file contains a virus of type Trojan Generic. I am certain that this warning only appears when I execute the MASM program I wrote, so it seems to be related to my code.

I would like to understand why this is happening. The antivirus software I am using is F-secure. Here is the code I wrote:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.code
main PROC 
mov eax,10000h  ; EAX = 10000h 
add eax,40000h  ; EAX = 50000h 
sub eax,20000h  ; EAX = 30000h
call DumpRegs   ; display registers
exit  
main ENDP 
END main
```

Thank you.

I have tried multiple times, but the antivirus software always displays a warning.

Comment: Antivirus software detects using heuristics, rules that let it guess that code might be a virus.  Something in your code looks suspicious to the AV software.  "False positives" can happen based on actions such as adding hooks, changing files, many different things.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_analysis  .  Some AV software like Microsoft's Defender let you mark a folder as safe, an exception, not to scan.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I have already modified MSAM to MASM. I didn't notice it earlier. Thank you.

Comment: MASM is Microsoft's Macro Assembler.  "Machine Specific Assembly Language" isn't a standard term or acronym.  Assembly is normally machine-specific, unless it's assembly language for VM bytecode or something.

Comment: Have you tried with other code like `mov eax, 30000h` / `mov edx, 12345h`?  I wonder if the anti-virus thinks it's suspicious to do useless computations at run-time using constants, i.e. a `mov`-immediate followed by an `add`-immediate on the same register?   Any sane compiler or programmer would have done the math at assemble time, and written `mov eax, 10000h + 40000h - 20000h` which assembles the same as `mov eax, 30000h`.  But shellcode sometimes does stuff like that to get a value in registers without having certain bytes in the machine code.

Comment: An executable is different, it doesn't have to work as a payload for `strcpy` or whatever, but perhaps virus scanners think they might be trying to avoid some byte sequence that virus scanners look for?  Hrm, `mov`-immediate followed by `add`-immediate on the same register could be plausible if there was a branch that jumped to just the add, so if that's really what it's looking for, that might have a lot of false positives.

Comment: I have tried the instructions you mentioned, but the antivirus software still gives a false positive. I think I may need to add my program to the exception list. Thank you for your assistance.